# How to create the JavaScript regular expression for number with some special symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the JavaScript regular expression which gives the numbers with some symbols. For example following condition must be pass.

1. Number can start with **$**
2. Can have the **.** or **,** **:** symbols between and
3. **%** sign at the send.

Passing values:

```
$233    48.23%   278  22.33  45:23  10,000
```

Number with any of this symbol gets separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches all given examples as well:

```
^\$?\d+(?:[.,:]\d+)?%?$
```

See it in action: [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/iY2bF7/1)

Please comment, if adjustment / further detail is required.

Comment: I want just \$?\d+(?:[.,:]\d+)?%?$ :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use following regex if you just want one of the characters `[.,:]` within your digits :

```
^\$?(?:\d+[.,:]?\d+|\d+)%?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT2lF8/5)

Comment: I was just about to hit submit button... Your solution is the correct one.